# EmEditor Professionalで以下のコマンドは可能でしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

EmEditor Professionalでお世話になっております。

EmEditor Professionalで以下のコマンドは可能でしょうか？

毎回正規表現の記述をしなくても

●検索にヒットした単語のある行全体を強調する、一部の単語のみでも行全体の検索ヒットにする

●強調した行全体を削除する

●強調した行以外を削除する(実質ヒットした単語の行のみ抽出)
同時に空行の削除も出来れば便利です。

正規表現で行全体をヒットさせることも可能かもしれませんが、普通の検索でもその単語の含まれる行全体を指定して気軽に削除か抽出できる方法です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

`検索` でなく `フィルター` 機能を使います。`フィルター` ツール バーに、検索したい文字列を入力すると、入力した文字列を含む行のみが表示されます。この時、`否定` ボタンをクリックすると、表示される行が反転されます。そして、`すべてブックマーク` ボタンをクリックすると、表示されている行のみにブックマークが設定され、`すべて抽出` ボタンをクリックすると、表示された行を抽出して新規文書を作成します。

[image: EmEditor フィルター]

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。出来ました。見事に素晴らしいソフトウェアです。

Comment: @三太郎 [誰かが回答したら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)を参考にしてみてください。「ありがとう」というコメントは必ずしも必要ありません